# URL manipulation while using reverse-proxy

Tags: reactjs, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have developed a reverse proxy using nginx which functions satisfactorily. 
I had a problem regarding the URL that is displayed on the browser.

Here's my config file:

```
server {
    listen       62106;
    server_name  example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/prs;

   location /perfreview/ {
        alias  /usr/share/nginx/html/prs;
        proxy_pass http://react-app:80/;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

The proxy works fine in the sense if I do http://example.com/perfreview/abc it proxies it to react-app:80/abc but the URL displayed on the browser after proxying is http://example.com/abc whereas I wish it to be http://example.com/perfreview/abc (original). Is there any way around it?

Last option would be to change routes in my react-app but that would require a lot of changes. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!